# Getting Error: Invalid output folder when using gulp-angular-templatecache to create a combined HTML template file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

I'm using Gulp for our build process. One of the major tasks it needs to accomplish is combining all our `.html` template partials from all the module folders into 1 `.js` templateCache file. Which creates just 1 download for the user for all the `HTML` files.

**[gulp-angular-templatecache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templatecache)**

---

Current Gulp require and config setup:

```
var gulp          = require('gulp'),
    gutil         = require('gulp-util'),
    gulpif        = require('gulp-if'),
    uglify        = require('gulp-uglify'),
    concat        = require('gulp-concat'),
    sass          = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    streamqueue   = require('streamqueue'),
    sourcemaps    = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    templateCache = require('gulp-angular-templatecache'),
    runSequence   = require('run-sequence'),
    del           = require('del'),
    es            = require('event-stream');

var config = {
    srcPartials:[
        'app/beta/*', 
        'app/header/**/*',
        'app/help/*',
        'app/login/*',
        'app/notificaitons/*',
        'app/panels/**/*',
        'app/popovers/**/*',
        'app/popovers/*',
        'app/user/*',
        'app/dashboard.html'
    ],
    destPartials: [
        'app/templates/'
    ]
};
```

The `html-templates` Gulp task:

```
/** HTML Template caching */
/** ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
gulp.task('html-templates', function() {
    return gulp.src(config.srcPartials)
    .pipe(templateCache())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.destPartials));
});
```

^ so as you can see above, I'm aiming to take all the .html files from all the folders listed in `srcPartials` and run `templateCache` on them and export out to the dest in `destPartials`.

However currently getting this error:

> Error: Invalid output folder
>       at Gulp.dest

At first I thought that this task didn't automatically create the folder, so I went ahead and created the `app/templates` folder, but still getting this error :( any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah just stumbled onto the answer: **The output folder is a string, not an array.**

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/496

~ [@stevelacy](https://github.com/stevelacy)

Comment: Now on to the next step: Getting the Directives to use the new `template.js` file